# data loss with (possibly) autovacumn

Tags: postgresql, odoo-11

I have customised the `crm` module in Odoo 11.

I added in some product lines to calculate planned revenue without having to create  a quotation.

The problem i have is that after a period of time - approx 1 day. the data is cleared from the fields in Odoo.

I set the fields correctly using `store=True` (i think!!)

The other suspect is the `autovacumn` scheduled action for the postgresql database clearing the data.

How can I ensure that the data remains and if it is up for `vacumming`, stop this from being garbage collected?

*crm_lead.py*

```
x_order_line = fields.One2many(
    "crm.lead.calc.revenue.line",
    "x_order_id",
    string="Product Lines",
    copy=False,
    auto_join=True,
    store=True,
)

x_product_id = fields.Many2one(
    "product.product",
    related="x_order_line.x_product_id",
    string="Product",
    copy=True,
)
```

*calc_revenue_line.py*

```
class CalcRevenue(models.TransientModel):
    """
    This wizard will Calculate the Planned Revenue of the current record in CRM.lead
    """

    _name = "crm.lead.calc.revenue.line"
    _description = "Line Model for Calculating products"

    x_product_id = fields.Many2one(
        "product.product",
        string="Product",
        domain=[("categ_id", "in", ["Accessories", "Final products", "Subscriptions"])],
        change_default=True,
        ondelete="restrict",
        required=True,
        store=True,
    )

    x_product_uom_qty = fields.Float(
        string="Quantity",
        digits=dp.get_precision("Product Unit of Measure"),
        required=True,
        default=1.0,
        store=True,
    )

    x_order_id = fields.Many2one(
        "crm.lead",
        string="Product Lines",
        required=True,
        ondelete="cascade",
        index=True,
        copy=False,
        store=True,
    )

    x_price_unit = fields.Float(
        "Unit Price", digits=dp.get_precision("Product Price"), default=1.0, store=True
    )
```

Comment: Autovacuum with *never* remove any visible rows.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Great information.. That is very useful to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing

`class CalcRevenue(models.TransientModel):`

to:

`class CalcRevenue(models.Model):`

I believe the `TransientModel` was responsible for not saving the data.